# ubuntu not booting after fixing windows and vice versa!

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, 14.04

after i installed Ubuntu 14.04 side to windows 8.1 , windows 8.1 wasn't booting then i install boot-repair to restore MBR ,after that windows 8.1 has been fixed and then Ubuntu wasn't booting then repeating using boot-repair and the loop didn't terminate!!
please anyone help me ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off [Fast Startup](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-or-enable-fast-startup-in-windows-8-1/) in Windows.

[image: Fast Startup]

Comment: i already turned it off and the problem still there!!

Comment: @user269783 If that option is checked you're going to have a bad time, as Windows is "hibernating" and not actually shut down.

Comment: i had unchecked the option before and it's still unchecked and return to ubuntu usb and used boot-repair but in this case ubuntu is return to boot but windows didn't boot and then used boot-repair to restore mbr but then ubuntu failed to boot!!

Comment: Is this a UEFI or a MBR system?

Comment: how could i know ?

Comment: @user269783 Read [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).